# Javascript and css file search path while running python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: javascript, python

I am running a python SimpleHTTPServer and serving a html file. That html file includes couple of javascript files. When the html file is served by the server I get the following errors.

```
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [15/Jun/2012 13:42:54] code 404, message File not found
1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa - - [15/Jun/2012 13:42:54] "GET /lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js
```

Html file contents (only relevant lines shown):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Python command used to run the server. It is run in the directory where index.html is present

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

I have the files jquery-ui-min.js in my local filesystem. But the search somehow is stripping the ../.. and searching in /lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 0):

If you run SimpleHTTPServer from a directory, it won't go above the root directory you run it from. This is a security feature.

For example, assuming the following layout:

```
/foo/bar/baz/index.html
/foo/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js
```

If you run SimpleHTTPServer from `/foo/bar/baz`, you won't be able to access any files above `/foo/bar/baz`. You could instead run the server from `/foo/` and it would work. You could also add symlinks in the baz directory up to the JavaScript you want to include.

Comment: Don't forget to explain how `../../` is resolved with regards to the web root.

Comment: Interesting... Is there a way to relax the security settings. I have quite a few files and creating sym links is really painful. And I am running this on my laptop, so security is not a big deal

Comment: No, but why don't you just run it from a higher directory?

Comment: @jterrace Regardless of the server's settings, requesting `../../lib` at `http://domain/` will **always** resolve to `http://domain/lib/`.